# How to correctly use regex in ruby test

Tags: ruby, regex

In a test, there is a random number at the end of a function output. I need to use regex. When I check the output manually, it works as intended. But my tests don't pass. Here's how it looks:

```
assert @tester.image == "http://loremflickr.com/300/300?random=#{/\d{1,3}/}"
```

The end of the url contains 1-3 digits. Example:

```
...random=476
```

How can I use regex properly in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`assert_match`](https://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_match) and avoid having to handle manually that procedure, making that more verbose. If your regular expression works fine, then:

```
assert_match /http:\/\/loremflickr\.com\/300\/300\?random=\d{1,3}/, @tester.image
```

Or for not having to escape specific characters:

```
%r{http://loremflickr\.com/300/300\?random=\d{1,3}}
```

Comment: First example worked after adding \ before .
`assert_match /http:\/\/loremflickr\.com\/300\/300\?random=\d{1,3}/`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot escaping the dot. Edited. Thanks!